# Deleting a pointer reference crashes the program

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I'm learning cpp by myself (I hope I didn't scare you off already), I understand what a pointer or a reference is and I think I get what a reference to a pointer is.

I've written a code that crashes at `delete[] ranking;` :

`open(file)` is just a simple function to open a txt file that contains a string and 3 integers each line which goes into `zuzel` structure:

```
void read_file(std::ifstream & file, zuzel *& ranking)
{
    if(!open(file))
    return; //exit function if reading a file failed

    int size = 1;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        zuzel * update = new zuzel[size];

        if(ranking != NULL) memcpy(update, ranking, (size-1)*sizeof(*ranking)); //copy existing contents

        file >> update[size - 1].nazwa >> update[size - 1].zawodnicy >> update[size - 1].mecze >> update[size - 1].punkty;// add a new team

        delete[] ranking; //delete old data
        std::cout << "tst"; //just to see if it crashes
        ranking = update;

        size++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    zuzel * rank;
    std::ifstream file;
    read_file(file, rank);
    return 0;
}
```

I found out that you shouldn't delete something that you didn't new, but for example that code doesn't crash :

```
void funk(int *& a)
{
    delete[] a;
}

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {3, 4, 6};
    int * p = a;
    funk(p);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix that crash? I'd be much obliged for some simple explanation why does it behave that way.

Comment: "Doesn't crash" doesn't mean the code is valid.

Comment: `I found out that you shouldnt delete something that you didnt new, but for example that code doesnt crash`  There is no guarantee that bad C++ code like this will crash.

Comment: `I'm learning cpp by myself`  Then may I suggest you learn to use `std::vector` instead of writing low-level C to simulate a dynamic array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be enough to write

```
zuzel * rank = 0;
```

As for the second code snippet then it has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
zuzel * rank;
//somewhere in read_file:
delete[] ranking; //ranking is a reference to pointer;
                 //in your case it's referernce to uninitialized pointer rank
```

Because `rank` is not initialized, it points to a unknown portion of memory, and your code simply tryes to `delete[]` the portion anyway...

You need to do set a pointer to address `0` by using one of these:

```
zuzel * rank=nullptr; //in C++11
zuzel * rank=NULL; //before C++11
zuzel * rank=0; //also legal, but I not recommend this
```

`0` is the special value for any pointer, meaning that it points to nothing.

When you pass pointer set to `0` to [`delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/) or [`delete`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/) they simply do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're learning. Please accept this example of how you might prefer to do it. You will find that it's exception-safe and avoids using pointers (and therefore avoids the need for memory management)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct zuzel 
{
    std::string nazwa, zawodnicy, mecze, punky;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const zuzel& z)
{
    return os << z.nazwa << ", " 
    << z.zawodnicy << ", "
    << z.mecze << ", "
    << z.punky;
}

std::vector<zuzel> read_zuzels(std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<zuzel> results;

    std::ifstream f(filename.c_str());
    f.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);

    while(!f.eof())
    {
        // add a new team
        zuzel new_zuzel;
        f >> new_zuzel.nazwa 
        >> new_zuzel.zawodnicy 
        >> new_zuzel.mecze 
        >> new_zuzel.punky;

        results.push_back(new_zuzel);
    }
    return results;
}

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<zuzel> zuzels = read_zuzels("input.txt");
    copy(zuzels.begin(), zuzels.end(), ostream_iterator<zuzel>(cout, "\n"));
   return 0;
}
```

input.txt:

```
foo1 bar1 baz1 bazzer1
foo2 bar2 baz2 bazzer2
```

output:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
foo1, bar1, baz1, bazzer1
foo2, bar2, baz2, bazzer2
```

Comment: The best thing you can do when learning c++ is to read up on the standard library. Here's a good place to start: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Best wishes in your c++ journey - since c++11 it's absolutely the most fun and productive language on the planet (IMHO).